# data is not shown in label using datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in the ASP.NET field and I made a function like:

```
public void lbtitle()
{
    IDataReader dr = d.FetchDataReader("SELECT top(5) ItineraryMaster.ItinerariesId, ItineraryMaster.Title FROM ItineraryMaster WHERE ItineraryMaster.Title = '" + lbltitle.Text + "'");

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        lbltitle.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
    }
}
```

and behind code is:

```
<asp:Label ID="Lbl_id" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItinerariesId") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
```

the control is not gone on the `dr.read()` function.
I don't know why this is happening.

and data reader code is:

```
public SqlDataReader FetchDataReader(string sqlQuery)
{    
     SqlDataReader tempDataReader = (SqlDataReader) objSqlDatabase.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, @sqlQuery);    
     return tempDataReader;    
}
```

Comment: Is the same query in DB returns any data?

Comment: Yes, this query work fine

Comment: can you update the question with `FetchDataReader` code?

Comment: what is d in "d.FetchDataReader"

Comment: here "d"is object of "DAL class"

Comment: so, the problem is that code inside IF block doesn't execute? From the code side, seems that FetchDataReader method doesn't return needed data. Is there any exception happens?

Comment: no, there no exception occurs

Comment: @user3093929 Data reader is connected object and you returning it as an object from your function that is why it is returning anything. Please check it.

Comment: @user3093929 Is this the full code for `lbtitle()` method ? Can you check if `Reader` has rows ?

Comment: Where is `lbtitle()` called? I mean, in `Page_Load()`, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

why you are confusing yourself.

complete all tasks inside using statement. no need to define multiple functions to implement this. here i have modified code . try this

```
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            cn.Open();
            string title = lbltitle.Text.Trim();
            string query = @"SELECT top(5) ItinerariesId, Title 
                            FROM ItineraryMaster WHERE ItineraryMaster.Title = @title";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", title));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lbltitle.Text = lbltitle.Text.ToString() + "<br/>" + dr["Title"].ToString();
            }
        }
```